# Why so many WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST in my message loop?

Tags: ime

In sonme environment， my progrmae's message loop was full with WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST , WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE and WM_IME_NOTIFY in order.

I really don't know where was the WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST posted from. It makes the api PeekMessage(..., PM_REMOVE) always returns nonezero so that I can't do my logic in idle time.

When it happens, maxium and minium the window after some times. The message loop becomes clear. And evething goes right. Or still busy with dealing WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST , WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE and WM_IME_NOTIFY loop.

It may happens when ime changes in the start of the programe launches.

Beg Help! Orz~~~~~。Sorry for my poor Engilsh.